# Show "Loading..." or "Fetching.." on screen for a while after selecting a value in dash dropdown

Tags: python, html, r, plotly-dash

I am curious to know if I can print something like "Loading.." on the screen for a while after clicking a value in dash dropdown.

sample dropdown :https://dashr.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown from dash website

I just want to let the user know that the results are being fetched for the option he has selected from the drop down list and then display the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a *Loading Component* in dash core :

> The Loading component can be used to wrap components that you want to
> display a spinner for, if they take too long to load. It does this by
> checking if any of the Loading components' children have a
> loading_state prop set where is_loading is true. If true, it will
> display one of the built-in CSS spinners.

You will find some examples in the [documentation](https://dashr.plotly.com/dash-core-components/loadingcomponent) page.